# How do i only showing a link on the one partial of the two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Ok so i have a rails form partial that is accessed by 2 views the new and edit action, but i only need to show a link on on edit form by i am trying this approach

new form

```
 = render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}
```

edit form

```
= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f, :show_link => true}
```

form partial

```
if defined? show_link
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or a standard rails way that is a better approach

Answer (score 1):

If it's a link and not a form element, it's generally better practice to have nested renders. In other words, you have 3 files: `new.html`, `edit.html`, and `_form.html`. Both `new.html` and `edit.html` render `_form.html`, and `edit.html` includes the extra link. You can style the link element to appear elsewhere if you need to.

If it's crucial that the link flow more elegantly into the form, consider using `content_for` and `yield`, so that `edit.html` includes:

```
content_for :extras do
    # link here
end
```

And `_form.html` then includes `yield :extras`.

NOTE: I deliberately left off template extensions, not knowing whether you're using erb, haml, other.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have seen this done before is using `new_record` and `persisted`, which are inverses of each other. `persisted` is for saved records, and `new_record` is for unsaved.

I'm going to guess at the scenario here, but is it something like 'show a delete link on the edit page'?

If so, I would do something like this (assuming @object is the object for the form):

(new and edit form)

```
= render 'form'
```

(form partial)

```
- if object.persisted?
  = link_to 'Delete', @object, :method => :delete
```

(examples are in haml but should be easy to convert to erb if necessary)

Answer (score 1):

you need not even pass the `parameter show_link` from edit, you can `detect the action` itself in `form view`.

in both the places you can use

```
<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

and in `form partial` you can do it like

```
<%= (link_to ........ ) if params[:action] == "edit" %>
```

if link is html tag, you can do it like

```
<% if params[:action] == "edit" %>
<a href="...">click me to edit</a>
<% end %>
```

So now it will check if the `render` happened from `edit` action, the `link` will be added.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like

```
if @record.new_record?
  # render 'new' partial
else
  # render 'edit' partial
end
```

to differ the `new` and `edit` specific things in my rails forms